# NSMutableArray is printing only the last element and not whole datas in the array

Tags: iphone, sqlite, nsmutablearray, ios5

Can anyone please help me out.I have been stuck with this NSMutableArray for last 2-3 days. I am beginner in Objective-C and I don't know what is the error in the code.In my program, I have created a sqlite database.It contain 3 fields and i have successfully inserted the values into db.And I am extracting these values from the db into NSMutableArray and displaying this array.But the problem is only last element is displaying and not whole data. I dont understand why it is displaying only the last element.I will paste the code below- Can anyone please check it and help me out.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

   databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TDL1.db"];

   const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

   sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &TDLDB) == SQLITE_OK)
         {
                    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT MYTASK, SUBTASK FROM TDL1 "];

                    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];



      if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(TDLDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)

       {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
              {
                     todolist2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

                      NSString *mytask = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

                      NSString *subtask = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

                   todolist2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:mytask,subtask, nil];

                       NSLog(@"THE array is:%@",todolist2);

       } 

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
              sqlite3_close(TDLDB);

}
         NSLog(@"THE outside array is:%@",todolist2);
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

And in the console I am getting the following output :-

```
2012-09-06 11:33:23.529 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
    task0,
    task0
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.532 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
    task1,
    task1
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.533 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
    task2,
    task2
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.534 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
    task3,
    task3
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.534 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
    task4,
    task4
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.535 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
    task5,
    task5
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.536 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
   task6,
   task6
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.537 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
    task6,
    task6
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.537 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
    task7,
    task7
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.538 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
    task7,
    task7
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.539 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
    task8,
    task8
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.539 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
    task9,
    task9
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.540 TDL[823:f803] THE array is:(
   task10,
   task10
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.540 TDL[823:f803] THE outside array is:(
   task10,
   task10
)
2012-09-06 11:33:23.541 TDL[823:f803] could not prepare statement: not an error
```

I want to display the values starting from task0 to task10.How to show that?Please tell me the solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have created that array inside while, create it before while loop

Comment: @problemchild :thank you.I got that. :)

Comment: @problemchild :I have one more doubt.I am displaying all these items in UItableView.Now I want to display these items in section.Means first array element in first section and 2nd element in section and so on. Can you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just making a new NSMutableArray each time you go through your `while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)` loop. Actually you are making one twice. Move the following line outside the while loop:

```
todolist2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Then inside your while loop instead of recreating a new array each time with:

```
todolist2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:mytask,subtask, nil];
```

Instead use:

```
[todolist2 addObject:myTask];
[todolist addObject:subTask];
```

These lines will add the two strings to the end of your array.

Comment: Thank you..I got that. :) I have one more doubt.I am displaying all these items in UItableView.Now I want to display these items in section.Means first array element in first section and 2nd element in section and so on. Can you please tell me how to do that?